# How to add character to numeric matrix in matlab?

Tags: matlab, matrix

In matlab usually we add a header using `fprintf` command.

This is a problem when the size of the table depends on the input and when it exceeds a certain range (more than total number of column able to be presented in the command window).

When this occurs the header which we specified previously using the `fprintf` command will not be compatible with the current output data.

I would like to know is there a way like adding a character string into the 1st row of the matrix during some kind of iteration process. I had tried hardly but still can't find a proper way to solve this issue.

Or it is actually cannot be done in matlab for this purpose.

Eg

```
clear;clc
A = [2 8 3 1;0 2 -1 4;7 -2 1 2;-1 0 5 2]
B = [-2;4;3;5]
Es = 1e-5


n = length(B);
x = zeros(n,1);
Ea = ones(n,1);
iter = 0;

while max(Ea) >= Es
    if iter <= 30
        iter = iter + 1;
        x_old = x;
        for i = 1:n
           j = 1:n;
           j(i) = [];
            x_cal = x;
            x_cal(i) = [];
            x(i) = (B(i) - sum(A(i,j) * x_cal)) / A(i,i);
        end
    else
        break
    end

    x_ans(:,iter) = x;
    Ea(:,iter) =abs(( x - x_old) ./ x);

    end

result = [1:iter; x_ans; Ea]'
```

for the coding above..how could I add the heading like iteration for 1st column, x1...x2...x3..xn for  `n`th column and error x1..error x2..error xn for another n column. I would like to make this heading can be automated generated based on the input matrix

Comment: Can you post an example of what you are trying and the result you are getting?

Comment: @grantnz i had edited my question..i would really like to know how it can be done..thx a lot!

Comment: It's still not clear what you are having problems doing.  You mention using fprintf to generate a header but your code doesn't use fprintf and doesn't generate a header.  Are you trying to generate a matlab matrix with a header row or print a matlab matrix with the printed output having a header row?

Answer (score 0):

If the size of the table depends on the input, use a cell array, using c = cell(...).
In each iteration simply call c{i,j} instead of c[i,j].

Comment: @LeeorI had added an example and I would like to know for this kind of case how the heading can be added and it will be flexible enough based on the input data